# Replace version number in file with sed in Bash script

Tags: linux, sed, version

In my `project.pro` file I have:

```
DEFINES += VERSION=\\\"1.13.1\\\"
```

I'd like to replace whatever the current version number is, with a new one in a Bash script:

```
VERSION_MAJOR=1
VERSION_MINOR=14
VERSION_PATCH=1

sed -i "s/\([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+\)/\1${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}/" project.pro
```

Why is that not working?

So far I have managed to get either no matches at all or then some weird replace-only-the-last-number substitutions.

Comment: Why \\\ is needed here?

Comment: It's some Qt project file garbage so that the value gets correctly passed on to the compiler as a string. The compiler must get `-DVERSION=\"1.13.1\"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak -E "s/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/$VERSION_MAJOR.$VERSION_MINOR.$VERSION_PATCH/" project.pro
```

Few problems in your attempt:

- Without extended regex mode (`-E`), `+` cannot be used unescaped.
- dot needs to be escaped in a regex
- No need to use a capture group and back-reference `\1`.

PS: `.bak` is extension of backup file so that you can get original file, in case of a wrong substitution.

Comment: What is that `.bak` ? It doesn't matter if it's there or not.

Comment: Added a note about  `.bak` in answer.